# RSelenium - Java enable

Tags: java, r, selenium, rselenium

I try to `startServer()` in RSelenium

but I receive this error:

```
Error in startServer():
Selenium binary error: Unable to start Selenium binary. Check java is installed.
```

I used cmd command java -version and I have java

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

What else should I do in order to start the server?

Comment: This error indicates the selenium server binary was unable to start. You can start the binary manually see http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/12843 or consider running a Docker container see http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Search for the jar file within RSelenium package (directory) and execute it from the console with:

```
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar
```

After that you can skip the `startServer()` line

Answer (score 0):

You can start selenium server with also with parameters:

```
java -jar ~/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -host localhost -port 4444 -role hub
```

and You can also start with bunch of parameters from eg. json config file

```
java -jar ~/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar -role hub -hubConfig $config"
```

and here is json config example:

```
{
  "_comment": "Configuration for local Hub",
  "host": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 4444,
  "maxSessions": 5,
  "cleanupCycle": 5000,
  "timeout": 30000,
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 180000,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher"
}
```